# Uppercase E notation for sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, boolean-algebra, universal-algebra

In Jónsson and Tarski's (1951) paper *[Boolean Algebras with Operators, Part I](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372123)* from the American Journal of Mathematics, they write formulae such as

$L_i = \underset{u}{\mathbf{E}} \, [u \in At^m \text{ and } u \leq x^{(i)}]$

and

$K = \underset{u}{\mathbf{E}} \, [y \geq u \in At^m]$,

without explaining this $\underset{u}{\mathbf{E}}$ notation. From the context, I guess these define sets, i.e., they respectively mean

$L_i = \{u \mid u \in At^m \text{ and } u \leq x^{(i)} \}$

and

$K = \{u \mid y \geq u \in At^m \}$.

Am I correct in this?

Also, is this notation something common that mathematicians generally understand? What does **E** stand for, and where did this notation originate? Are there good books/articles/webpages where I can learn about this notation?

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Additional note. To give some context, on p. 900, following the first formula, they proceed to define $K = \bigcup_{i \in I} L_i$ (which has nothing to do with the $K$ in the second of the formulae above) and say that $u \in K$ if and only if $\sum_{i \in I} x^{(i)} \geq u \in At^m$. In order for this equivalence to hold, it seems to me that $L_i = \{u \mid u \in At^m \text{ and } u \leq x^{(i)} \}$.

$At$ denotes the set consisting of $0$ and all the atoms of a Boolean algebra $A$. For my interpretation to make sense, however, I suppose that $At^m$ should be the set consisting of $0$ and all the atoms of $A^m$, and not the $m$-times product of $At$.

Comment: An 'E' with brackets commonly denotes an expected value, as from probability theory.  Given that they are writing a $u$ in the subscript, they could be defining $L_i$ to be the expected value of $u$ over some event, and similarly for $K$.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with probability theory or expected values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather old paper, so it is not a surprise to find some outdated notation. AFAIK, this $\mathbf{E}$ is not in frequent use anymore, may mean something like *ensemble* (French for “set”).

Indeed, we have the equality
$$
\underset{u}{\mathbf{E}} \, [u \in At^m \text{ and } u \leq x^{(i)}] = \{u \mid u \in At^m \text{ and } u \leq x^{(i)}\},
$$
but you have to take into account that each $x^{(i)}$ is an $m$-tuple of elements of $A$, and the notation $u \leq x^{(i)}$ is defined by the “pointwise” comparison, that is, $u_j\leq x^{(i)}_j$ for all $j$. Then $At^m$ is actually an $m$-tuple of atoms.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is really helpful!
As for $At^m$, I thought that if it denoted the set of $m$-tuples of elements of $At$, then the equivalence between $u \in K$ and $\sum_{i \in I} x^{(i)} \geq u \in At^m$ would not hold.

Suppose $At^m$ denotes the set of $m$-tuples of elements of $At$.
Let $0 \neq a \in At$, $m = 3$, $I = \{0, 1, 2\}$, $x^{(0)} = (a, 0, 0)$, $x^{(1)} = (0, a, 0)$, $x^{(2)} = (0, 0, a)$ and $u = (a, a, 0)$. Then $\sum_{i \in I} x^{(i)} = (a, a, a) \geq u \in At^m$, but since there is no $i \in I$ with $u \leq x^{(i)}$, we have $u \notin K$.
Am I mistaken?

Comment: Also, may I ask where you learned about this notation? Are there any books etc. that introduce this notation?

Comment: @Usagi It seems that you're missing an hypothesis appearing in the proof of the theorem, namely, that the $x^{(i)}$'s agree coordinatewise except at most for one coordinate $j$. Concerning the notation, I had to guess.

Comment: Ah! You are absolutely right. I was not paying attention to the whole proof. Thank you so much. I'm really grateful for your kind help.

Comment: @Usagi You're welcome!